# jQuery on my website was working for 6 months, now all of a sudden stopped

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

http://www.chocolatvitale.com

can someone please tell me why my jQuery Validation, Slideshow and AjaxLink
plugins stopped working on this site? the header of the document looks like this:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#contact").validate();  
      $(".ajaxLink").ajaxLink();
      $(".slideshow").cycle({
   fx: 'fade'
    });
   });
   </script>
```

Anyone have an idea of what happened? thank you so much!

yes I know my stylesheet is all in the header, I did it on purpose

Comment: You're not saying what behaviour you're expecting. An example of what doesn't work anymore would be helpful

Answer (score 3):

You are calling `http://dev.jquery.com/view/trunk/plugins/validate/jquery.validate.js`, which is returning `403 Forbidden`.  You should store the file on your own server, and call it there.

I imagine jQuery's server has been configured to reject requests that seem to come from other sites, in order to save their bandwidth.

---

**Edit** As pointed out in the comments, you could use a [CDN](http://en.wikipedia.org/Content_delivery_network) to host your file.

**Edit 2** Also, your image preloading scripts are broken. They're obfuscated, so I can't read them, but the problem is that `d.#contacts.length` (line 54) is invalid Javascript.

Comment: @Andrew Whitaker Perhaps I'm mistaken, but I don't know of any CDN that hosts the validate plugin...

Comment: http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/cdn.ashx#jQuery_Validation_Releases_on_the_CDN_2 (microsoft).  Google doesn't appear to host validate.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery has announced that [they will no longer serve jQuery.js from their servers](http://blog.jquery.com/2010/12/30/hotlinking-to-be-disabled-on-jan-31-2011/), but it was supposed to end on Jan 31.  Maybe they flipped the switch early?

Answer (score 0):

I know someone anwsered your question but here is an advice how to figure out those kind of problems on your own.

get FireBug http://getfirebug.com/